# Disable selecting text anywhere

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij 14

I am expecting that when I select empty space to the right of a line, my cursor will go to the end of the line.

Right now, I can click anywhere to the right of a line, and my cursor will go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had pressed alt-shift-insert which [toggles between line and column selection modes](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d1526996e255).

Pressing alt-shift-insert again took me back to line selection mode.